# Extract just the front page code from template

Tags: front-matter, covers

[This](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/it-university-copenhagen) is a template I want to use as part of an assignment. The thing is that I only need the frontpage. But no matter how I try to get only the code for the frontpage by trying to delete everything that doesn't have anything to do with the frontpage, it just bugs up for whole document. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
% Use this package: 
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text
% In your document add the first page as your start page. 
% Rest of the document will follow normally. 
\begin{document}
    \includepdf[pages={1}]{YOUR_TEMPLATE.pdf}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```